# Seeking a statistical javascript function to return p-value from a z-score

Tags: javascript, jstat

I need to convert z-scores to percentile. I found reference to a [function in the jStat library](http://jstat.github.io/test.html#jStat.ztest) that I could use (jstat.ztest), but the jStat documentation seems to be ahead of the available library because there is no such function in the [currently available version of the library](http://www.jstat.org/jstat-1.0.0.js).

I think there is a [more recent version of the library on GitHub](https://github.com/jstat/jstat), which may include the ztest function, but I am a linux novice and could not figure out how to build the library from the instructions. I spent most of a day learning about git bash and cygwin trying to build the library; I finally decided I'd be better off asking here.

So, could anyone point me toward a javascript function that would do what I need?
Alternatively, could anyone point me toward a built version of the jStat library with ztest function included?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found this in a forum online and it works like a charm.

```
function GetZPercent(z) 
  {
    //z == number of standard deviations from the mean

    //if z is greater than 6.5 standard deviations from the mean
    //the number of significant digits will be outside of a reasonable 
    //range
    if ( z < -6.5)
      return 0.0;
    if( z > 6.5) 
      return 1.0;

    var factK = 1;
    var sum = 0;
    var term = 1;
    var k = 0;
    var loopStop = Math.exp(-23);
    while(Math.abs(term) > loopStop) 
    {
      term = .3989422804 * Math.pow(-1,k) * Math.pow(z,k) / (2 * k + 1) / Math.pow(2,k) * Math.pow(z,k+1) / factK;
      sum += term;
      k++;
      factK *= k;

    }
    sum += 0.5;

    return sum;
  }
```

And I don't need to include a large library just for the one function.

Comment: To clarify since this offers no explanation/citation whatsoever: this is based on a Taylor expansion of the integral of the normal standard distribution: http://math2.org/math/stat/distributions/z-dist.htm - the ambiguity of the operator precedence on the `term = ` line makes this very difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

Just editing the code from Paul's answer for a two-sided t-test

```
function GetZPercent(z) 
{
//z == number of standard deviations from the mean

//if z is greater than 6.5 standard deviations from the mean
//the number of significant digits will be outside of a reasonable 
//range
if ( z < -6.5)
  return 0.0;
if( z > 6.5) 
  return 1.0;

if (z > 0) { z = -z;}

var factK = 1;
var sum = 0;
var term = 1;
var k = 0;
var loopStop = Math.exp(-23);
while(Math.abs(term) > loopStop) 
{
  term = .3989422804 * Math.pow(-1,k) * Math.pow(z,k) / (2 * k + 1) / Math.pow(2,k) * Math.pow(z,k+1) / factK;
  sum += term;
  k++;
  factK *= k;

}
sum += 0.5;

return (2*sum);
}
```

Comment: You should put your if statement to the very begin of this function. Otherwise it will return 1 when z > 6.5, which should be 0 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like such a simple ask but I had a hard time tracking down a library that does this instead of copying some random code snippet. Best I can tell this will calculate z-score from a percentage using the simple-statistics library.

I took their documentation about cumulativestdnormalprobability and backed into the following algorithm. Feels like there should be an easier way but who knows.

https://simplestatistics.org/docs/#cumulativestdnormalprobability

```
const z_score = inverseErrorFunction((percentile_value - 0.5) / 0.5) * Math.sqrt(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already correctly stated by Shane, the equation is an implementation of the Taylor Expansion of the normal cdf. The `sum` value iterates above and below the "real" value with increasing precision. If the value is close to 1 or 0 there is a very low, but existing, probability that `sum` will be >1 or <0, because of the (relatively) early break by `loopstop`.
The deviation is further strengthened by rounding `1/Math.sqrt(2*Math.Pi)` to `0.3989422804` and the precision issues of javascript float numbers. Additionally, the provided solution will not work for z-scores >7 or <-7

I updated the code to be more accurate using the [decimal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js) npm library and to directly return the p-value:

```
function GetpValueFromZ(_z, type = "twosided") 
{
    if(_z < -14)
    {
        _z = -14
    }
    else if(_z > 14)
    {
        _z = 14
    }
    Decimal.set({precision: 100});

    let z = new Decimal(_z);
    var sum = new Decimal(0);

    var term = new Decimal(1);
    var k = new Decimal(0);

    var loopstop = new Decimal("10E-50");
    var minusone = new Decimal(-1);
    var two = new Decimal(2);

    let pi = new Decimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647")

    while(term.abs().greaterThan(loopstop)) 
    {
        term = new Decimal(1)
    
        for (let i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            term = term.times(z).times(z.dividedBy(two.times(i)))
        }
    
        term = term.times(minusone.toPower(k)).dividedBy(k.times(2).plus(1))        
        sum = sum.plus(term);
        k = k.plus(1);
    }
    
    sum = sum.times(z).dividedBy(two.times(pi).sqrt()).plus(0.5);

    if(sum.lessThan(0))
        sum = sum.abs();
    else if(sum.greaterThan(1))
        sum = two.minus(sum);

    switch (type) {
        case "left":
            return parseFloat(sum.toExponential(40));
        case "right":
            return parseFloat((new Decimal(1).minus(sum)).toExponential(40));
        case "twosided":
            return sum.lessThan(0.5)? parseFloat(sum.times(two).toExponential(40)) : parseFloat((new Decimal(1).minus(sum).times(two)).toExponential(40))
        
    }

}
```

By increasing the Decimal.js `precision` value and decreasing the `loopstop` value you can get accurate p-values for very small (or very high) z-scores for the cost of calculation time.